# Expectation of a function of two different transformations of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

I have a random variable $X$ where the support of $X$ is non-negative and I want to compute the expectation of $aX\log(bX)$ where $a,b>0$

If I can chose how $X$ is distributed, is there a non-degenerate distribution that will enable me to compute the closed form of the expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is uniform on $(0,\theta)$, one can introduce $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$ to compute
$$
E(aX\log(bX))=a\theta\log(b\theta)E(U)+a\theta E(U\log U),
$$
with
$$
E(U)=\int_0^1u\,\mathrm du=\frac12,\qquad E(U\log U)=\int_0^1u\log u\,\mathrm du=-\frac14.
$$
Likewise, if $X$ is beta $(c,1)$, then $X$ has density $cx^{c-1}$ on $(0,1)$ hence
$$
E(aX\log(bX))=a\log(b)E(X)+aE(X\log X),
$$
with
$$
E(X)=\int_0^1cx^c\,\mathrm dx=\frac{c}{c+1},\qquad E(X\log X)=\int_0^1cx^c\log x\,\mathrm dx=-\frac{c}{(c+1)^2}.
$$

Comment: The first equation looks weird - there are occurences of $x$ outside the expectation operator... Either I'm missing something, or you miss-typed there.

Comment: @fgp Nothing weird here, $x$ is a positive real number while $X$ is a random variable. Changed $x$ to $\theta$.

Comment: Uh, yeah, true. But I like the new notation much better ;-)

Comment: @fgp Thanks for notifying me the (possibility of a) confusion.

Comment: @Did Anything with support from 0 to +infinity?

Comment: Sure. Tell me. $ $

Comment: @Did say a gamma  or Wald distribution?

Comment: If E(X) and E(X.log(X)) can be managed, you get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but without a specific distribution we can't go further than this:

Denote the law of $X$ by $\mathscr{L}_X$ and, if $X$ has a density, then denote this by $f_X$. Then we know that

$$ \mathbb{E}(aX \log(bX)) =  a \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \log(bx)\mathscr{L}_X(dx) =  a \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \log(bx) f_X (x) (dx). $$

Comment: He explicitly said "If I can *choose* how $X$ is distributed..."

Comment: *And I said*, you can't go any further than the above... This would amount to being able to solve the equation $x\log(x) = \alpha$ analytically for x.

Comment: "This would amount to being able to solve the equation xlog(x)=α analytically for x." To compute the expectation? This is not always necessary.

Comment: @Frank Why? If, for example, $X$ only takes finitely many values, then $\mathbb{E}(aX\log(bX))$ is a *finite* sum, which certainly qualifies as a closed form...

Comment: Yes, but then (exactly as I said) you are giving more distributional information about $X$!

Comment: Telling me that the distribution of $X$ is concentrated on a countable set counts as giving me more information about the distribution of $X$. Or am I misunderstanding something?  :S

Comment: You might be missing the part "is there a non-degenerate distribution that will enable me to compute the closed form of the expectation?" of the question.

Comment: @Frank You are. The question is about finding *one particular* distribution such that $\mathbb{E}(...)$ has a closed form. The only restriction is that the distribution isn't supposed to be *degenerate*, whatever that means (maybe that $X$ takes more than a single value). So, you're not *given* any information about $X$, but you may *assume* as much as you want to, as long as it's non-contradictory...

Comment: OK. So the OP is simply asking for an example of a distribution of X where this can be done, as supplied by Did? In that case the question is surely trivial. Just set $X = 1$ a.s. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Woops yes I am. It needs to be 'non-degenerate'. My bad.

Comment: Still, a badly worded question (in my opinion).